# Network or networking?

Tags: discussion, tags

I went to tag a network-related question with one and ended up with:

network x 37
networking x 26

There is also indicator-network and network-manager, which I think are useful to keep around. But for these two? Should we just pick the popular one or discuss it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think both have a vague difference about them, and when I see the questions that link to these I realize why some would call it "network" and others "networking". Ideally these should probably be merged as you're correct - they are the same thing.

As for which tag we should use - Ideally you'd want to take the one that's used most. However on other SE websites `networking` is the one preferred and I believe it encompasses that of what is tagged in `network`

Comment: Agreed. `networking` makes the most sense IMO and we should probably merge so the `network` tag no longer exists. That should stop newcomers accidentally using it.

Comment: Agreed. similar tags would just confuse newcomers.

Comment: I assume the mod tools allow you to merge tags, or do we have to go rename them by hand?

Comment: @Jorge There are mod tools for that. I'll start the merging process. However, users can propose merges from the tags page (for future reference)